# How to import the 'listpicker' control in vs2012 for windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I downloaded the Silverlight for windows phone Toolkit,but I don't konw how to import it to vs2012.I searched the method on the Internet,only finding the method for vs2010.And I found it doesn't fit for vs2012.So what's the method for vs2012 to import the Toolkit to use the control 'listpicker'?

Answer (score 0):

A great free extension for Visual Studio 2012 is the [NuGet Package Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c). It will handle the adding or removing of packages to your VS project. I used this to import the ToolKit.

Once NuGet is installed, in VS go to Project > Manage NuGet Packages... Search for "Windows Phone Toolkit" and click Install. That's it.